# Stackoverflow not happening while trying to figure out if memory is being allocated on stack or heap

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, stack-overflow

I wanted to try out a more complex example of allocating memory with new in an object and allocating further inside it, but needed to know for sure when a stackoverflow will happen. So decided to try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables) example. I called the `foo()` function from `main()` and expected it to give a stackoverflow error. It didn't. In foo, I increased the array size by a few more zeros and added 40 more such array declarations in foo. Still didn't crash.
Am using gcc version 4.4.2 20091027 (Red Hat 4.4.2-7) (GCC). Shouldn't a stack allocation of approx more than 1MB give a stackoverflow error?

```
void foo()
{
 double x[100000000];    
 double x1[100000000];    
 double x2[100000000];    
 double x3[100000000];    
 double x4[100000000];    
 //...and many more
}

int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

Compiled as gcc -o test test.c

Comment: if you have nothing interesting in the foo function the optimizer might remove it from the program. (and main should return an int)

Comment: @MByD: the `return` statement in `main` is optional (exceptional case permitted by standard).

Comment: Access some elements in the arrays (i.e. the first and the last) and see if that triggers the error you expect. In general, creation of a variable for which no constructor is run in the stack is implemented as an offset to a pointer (stack pointer) if you do not access the memory, then there will be no problems. Plus the fact that if the compiler can detect that the arrays are not used, then it can remove the variables altogether, and collide the function into `void foo(){}`

Comment: Yes. Array operations caused a segmentation fault. So I guess it was the optimization after all. I was expecting a 'stackoverflow' message to be displayed. Was surprised to see 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make foo call itself recursively, and have some counter increment with each call. You'll get your fault soon enough.

Comment: Yup, it gave a segmentation fault allright, but the real question was about why it didn't happen without recursion. I guess optimization was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile without optimization with -o0

Comment: Nope. Compiling without optimization didn't help.